# How to add time zone information to existing time.Time

Tags: go, time, timezone

Let's say that I have the following:

- A table in a Postgres database with a `TIMESTAMP` column.
- The database time zone set to something other than UTC.
- Some SQL statements that insert timestamp values with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `NOW()`

As stated in Postgres documentation:

> The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function returns a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE that represents the date and time at which the transaction started.

Therefore the following statement is silently converting a local timestamp into an absolute timestamp:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (id, timestamp_column) VALUES (0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Let's say that a Go program reads this data into a `time.Time` object, that object will have an empty `Location`:

```golang
fmt.Println(timeFromDb.Location().String() == "") // true
```

which is interpreted as UTC. At this point I do know that the Go time `timeFromDb` is not actually UTC, and I also know what the database time zone setting is.

How can I set the correct time zone into this time object? In practice:

```golang
// before
fmt.Println(timeFromDb)            // 2009-11-10 10:00:00
fmt.Println(timeFromDb.Location()) // <empty>
fmt.Println(timeFromDb.UTC())      // 2009-11-10 10:00:00

// magic?

// after
fmt.Println(timeFromDb)            // 2009-11-10 10:00:00
fmt.Println(timeFromDb.Location()) // America/Vancouver
fmt.Println(timeFromDb.UTC())      // 2009-11-10 18:00:00
```

Comment: if column in table is pure timestamp without time zone - then information already lost and you cannot convert it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reinterpret it:

```
loc,_:=time.LoadLocation("America/Vancouver")
t2:=timeFromDb.In(loc)
_,off:=t2.Zone()
theTime:=t2.Add(-time.Duration(off)*time.Second)
```

You can also do some string manipulation, but I suspect this is faster.

Comment: Keep in mind that while this will probably work for most values, it may have some errors near transitions (start/stop of DST, or change in standard time).  In other words, the offset at that UTC value may not be the same as the offset at that local time.